# Cannot override list.phtml in module

Tags: magento2, module

I've created a module that modifies `list.phtml` to eventually place some data under the price in product category listing. I'm using Magento 2.4.1.

Module can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g24ut8cwp11esle/payment-plan.zip?dl=0

The module loads, but when it does I am getting the following error when trying to view category pages:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Argument/Interpreter/DataObject.php:61]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Argument\Interpreter\DataObject->evaluate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php:61]
#6 Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Argument/Interpreter/Decorator/Updater.php:47]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Argument\Interpreter\Decorator\Updater->evaluate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:320]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->evaluateArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:68]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:587]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:545]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php:249]
#23 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#27 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#28 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php:23]
#29 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#31 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#32 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#33 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php:32]
#34 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#39 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#41 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

`app/code/jr2/payment-plan/etc/module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="JR2_PaymentPlan"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/jr2/payment-plan/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` (this data is copied as is from `Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="image" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Category\Image</argument>
                        <argument name="output" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Category\Output</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And finally `app/code/jr2/payment-plan/view/templates/product/list.phtml` (again, this is copied as is from `Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $_helper */
$_helper = $block->getData('outputHelper');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty">
        <div><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() === 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <li class="item product product-item">
                    <div class="product-item-info"
                         id="product-item-info_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_product->getId() ?>"
                         data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                        <?php
                        $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                        if ($pos != null) {
                            $position = 'left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                                . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php // Product Image ?>
                        <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                           class="product photo product-item-photo"
                           tabindex="-1">
                            <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">
                            <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link"
                                   href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                    <?=/* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                            <div class="product-item-inner">
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <div class="actions-primary">
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()):?>
                                            <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                                  data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                                  action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                                  method="post">
                                                <?php $optionsData = $block->getData('viewModel')->getOptionsData($_product); ?>
                                                <?php foreach ($optionsData as $optionItem): ?>
                                                    <input type="hidden"
                                                           name="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['name']) ?>"
                                                           value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['value']) ?>">
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                       name="product"
                                                       value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                       name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                       value="<?=
                                                       /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]
                                                       ?>">
                                                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary"
                                                        disabled>
                                                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                            <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                                                <div class="stock available">
                                                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else:?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ?
                                        /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                            $position,
                                            'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-primary'
                                        ) : '' ?>
                                    <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ?
                                        /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                            $position,
                                            'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-secondary'
                                        ) : '' ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute(
                                            $_product,
                                            $_product->getShortDescription(),
                                            'short_description'
                                        ) ?>
                                        <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                           title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ?
                        /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                            $position,
                            'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.product-item-actions'
                        ) : '' ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setIsBottom(true)->toHtml() ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= $escaper->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried:

- Overriding `list.html` in a them without overriding `catalog_category_view.xml` and just overriding the `list.phtml`. This causes the same problem.

Can anybody help me figure out what is causing this?

Edit: Following the suggestion in the comment with a link to another question I replace the contents of `catalog_category_view.xml` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="JR2_PaymentPlan::product/list.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is what I see on the frontend:

[image]

Comment: @RahulBarot already tried this. I still get the same error as above.

Comment: If you notice in the question I've put the path to where the original `list.html` is. It's a core in Magento module: `Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`. I've also edited the question to show what I see when I add `<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="JR2_PaymentPlan::product/list.phtml"/>`.

Comment: @RahulBarot as I've already said in the question I have attempted to do the same in my theme and I get exactly the same error. Also, the custom module is needed because I need to implement more features for this module once I get this working. I've put the module on dropbox, link in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

please revert all other code for override list.phtml

I dont know why you added below code. I can't able to find in core "catalog_category_view.xml" file. please remove this code and also clear cache after made changes in xml file

```
 <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: This does solve this error and I had already done this, but the second error in my image is related. Because in both cases it's the product options model that can't be found. The effected line in the error is `<?php $optionsData = $block->getData('viewModel')->getOptionsData($_product); ?>. I will accept as it solves the error I questioned.